# Can You Tell What the Answer Is?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, cryptic-clues

> It's Rodent the first in an oil bloc found
>   A twitch that tags on to a story in sound
>   Like Wotan it turns an irate cop around.
>   It's a long span of time, in a visual way.
>   *That* is the word that I'm trying to say.

The answer is a single English word. There are five clues, all found in the first four lines. This is a cryptic crossword style puzzle. The clues are four ways to construct the word and a definition.

Comment: Now that you've elaborated I've gone ahead and added the [tag:cryptic-clues] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word is

> Operatic

It's Rodent the first in an oil bloc found

> OPEC, with "rat I" ("rat the first") inside

A twitch that tags on to a story in sound

> Twitch = tic, story in sound = opera

Like Wotan

> Wotan is a character in Wagner's *[Ring Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Ring_des_Nibelungen)* operas

it turns an irate cop around.

> Operatic is an anagram of "irate cop"

It's a long span of time, in a visual way.

> "era" inside "optic"

Can You Tell What the Answer Is?

> The title contains a reference to [William Tell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tell_(opera))

Comment: And for absolute completeness Wotan (and Tell in the title) are characters in famous operas.